# How to patch a dependency of a npm library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependencies, npm

I experienced a bug in a deep dependency of a library installed using the npm.
I fixed that bug in a fork and created a [pull request](https://github.com/dominictarr/crypto-browserify/pull/66) on github.

I'm wondering how to share my fix with my co-workers. 
I found this [article](http://debuggable.com/posts/how-to-fork-patch-npm-modules:4e2eb9f3-e584-44be-b1a9-3db7cbdd56cb) but since it's not my dependency but a dependency of a library I use I don't know how to solve this problem.

Even if my pull-request get's accepted fast, I need to wait for the maintainer of the library to update his dependencies, what may never even happen.

Is there any common way how to solve such a thing?

Comment: If the license permits, you could make your own library npm module and make that a dependency instead.

Comment: Yes, but then i will find myself maintaining a lot of 3rd party libraries from time to time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

by using [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package), you can patch the dependency of a dependency like:

`npx patch-package package/another-package`

or in scoped package

`npx patch-package @my/package/@my/other-package`

please check [the package docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package)

Answer (score 4):

This library appears to be targeting this issue: https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

If the license of the original library allows you to take and modify it as you wish, you could clone it and submit your own NPM module (a relatively easy process) with the properly fixed submodule. Or just check that into your company's repository and don't include it on your package.json as a dep (to prevent it from overwriting it with npm install).

Answer (score 0):

Or you can create a patch and apply it in the 'postinstall' phase.

Comment: I mean, if you're using, say a version of some dependency that is incompatible with the version of another and they're not yet supported to work together, then maybe that change is being considered by the maintainer in a bigger set of changes for full compatibility (while yours may only work with your project).