# npx patch-package for sub-dependency

Tags: react-native, npm, patch-package

I have two versions of a module installed, one that is a direct dependency, and the other of which is a sub-dependency:

```
./node_modules/@react-navigation/native/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler
./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler
```

I have a code change to fix a compatibility problem with the first copy of react-native-gesture-handler above.  But this is a sub-dependency of react-navigation.

If I try to do `npx patch-package react-navigation` it finds no changes.  If I try to do `npx patch-package react-native-gesture-handler` it patches the second copy, which is not what I need.

Is there any way to use `npx patch-package` to patch a sub-dependency like above?

Comment: have you checked this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/74265028/11762907

Comment: Thanks that did help!  I did see that this syntax should work `npx patch-package @react-navigation/react-native-gesture-handler` but it still didn't find the sub package -- but then I tried this variation, which did work:  `npx patch-package @react-navigation/native/react-native-gesture-handler`.  I'm not sure what the extra `native` in the passed path does, or why it is necessary.

Comment: yes native is necessary because inside the native you have node module and you want this module to patch

Comment: patch package will check package.json

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem.  If you'd like to add this as an answer, I'll gladly accept -- I think it is different enough from the other question because of the /native/ path complication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npx patch-package@react-navigation/react-native-gesture-handler` will not work because the patch package will check your package.json file inside `/native` folder and native is necessary because inside native you need to patch that node module.

```
npx patch-package@react-navigation/react-native-gesture-handler
```

to

```
npx patch-package@react-navigation/native/react-native-gesture-handler
```